# Do I really need client certificates to be signed by a trusted CA?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate

Suppose I have a site that I want users to be able to log into with client certificates.  As I understand it, the client is presenting the site with the public half of a keypair and proving that they have the corresponding private half.  Is that correct?  If so, then isn't checking that a client is presenting a known (previously-authorized) public key sufficient to know that it's a known user, without the certificate having been signed by a trusted CA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use client-certificate authentication, towards the end of the handshake, the client sends a [`Certificate Verify` TLS message](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4346#section-7.4.8) where it signs with its private key the concatenation of all the TLS messages that have been exchanged between the client and the server: something commonly known by both.

This is independent of whether the client-certificate is trusted or not. The server still has verify the signature against the public key presented in the client certificate. If it failed, the handshake would fail.

At the end of the handshake, whether or not the server trusts what the certificate asserts, that is, the binding between the public key, the identifier and various other attributes, it will know at least that the client has the private key for the public key in this certificate (the rest may or may not be true).

If you have a pre-defined list of know public keys (akin to public keys you would set up for an SSH connection, for example), you can perform authentication this way. What you miss out on is the PKI: the whole infrastructure to help you manage the keys and who they belong to. Since most configuration settings are intended for use within a PKI, this may also need more work (including additional programming perhaps).

All the other properties of the TLS connection are intact: the encryption is still guaranteed in the same way as it would be within the context of a PKI. I'm not sure what @WesleyDavid is talking about in his answer on this subject. Anyway, it's about client certificates, so encryption between the client and the server would take place anyway, whether or not a client-certificate is presented (provided a cipher suite with non-null encryption is used, of course).

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can do this, but you lose the benefits of a CA. The benefit of a CA is that you only need to know the CA, you don't need to know every client individually beforehand. If you use a scheme where you recognize only the key, you'll need to individually configure each key in the server. If you just want to know that it's the same user, then you can just confirm it's the same public key.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, and you ***can*** do that, by having clients self-sign every certificate and manually trust each one of those as its own root CA, instead of having them signed by a trusted CA at all.

But there really isn't much sense in doing that - it sounds like you have clients who ***have*** certificates that are signed by a trusted CA.  Are you just trying to avoid the trust relationship validation step?

Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to understand how/why some sites seem to allow me to authenticate with just about any client certificate—e.g., there are sites that will let me use a MyOpenID-issued client certificate to authenticate, even though it's not signed by a standard trusted authority.  It's possible that such sites just have a really large list of root certificates that they trust, including the MyOpenID one, but that seems unlikely.  I'm also trying to understand why it matters whether or not I trust the root CA if I'm only verifying that I'm seeing the same certificate as I've seen before.

Comment: In OpenID, the site doesn't trust your certificate.  They interface with your OpenID provider, trusting them to provide your identity; your OpenID provider is the one who authenticates you using that certificate.  If you're verifying a certificate that you've seen before, did you trust its root signing certificate when you saw it last time?  Why would you keep track of a list of known certs (which web servers do not), when you can just validate the trust relationship of the certificate (while also doing some of the other neat things that certificates do like revocation checks)?

Comment: If the certificates are a means of authentication, then I have to keep track of how they map to my internal users in some fashion, whether or not I'm validating the issuer.  Being able to validate the issuer and check against revocation lists would be nice, but would severely limit which certificates users could use to authenticate, since I'd have to maintain a list of allowed CAs in advance (and this becomes difficult if I want to allow smartcard-based certificates, where the issuers vary and aren't necessarily already system-wide trusted CAs).

Answer (score 2):

> Suppose I have a site that I want users to be able to log into with
>   client certificates.

To be clear, we're talking about logging in with certificates and not speaking of any encryption topics.

> As I understand it, the client is presenting the site with the public
>   half of a keypair and proving that they have the corresponding private
>   half. Is that correct?

That is correct for keypair authentication.

> If so, then isn't checking that a client is presenting a known
>   (previously-authorized) public key sufficient to know that it's a
>   known user, without the certificate having been signed by a trusted
>   CA?

It's sufficient to know that the client trying to authenticate has the private key (and perhaps the private key password if it's been protected that way). As long as this is merely for authentication and not encryption, you don't need to worry about certificate authorities. You just need to collect public keys and delegate authority based on those keys appropriately.

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about w.r.t. to encryption. Using a client-cert doesn't have any impact on the shared-key negotiation in the SSL/TLS handhsake. It's always just for authentication anyway.